# How to delete all the commits before a specific commit in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've a project in Bitbucket feed via git Bash with too much commits and I want to conserve only the 5 last commits and delete all the commits before. For example for the next sequence

Last commits:

```
            6546464
            3684636
            3684368
            5785447
            3485888
            5784361
            6843684
            3878466
            3438438
```

Oldest commit: `3843838`

I want to save only the newest commits `6546464, 3684636, 3684368, 5785447, 3485888` and delete all the others committed before (can be hundreds)

How to do this clean action with git bash?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by too much commits?

Comment: Also see https://passingcuriosity.com/2017/truncating-git-history/